# wsimport not writing code

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl

I've setup a basic web service, I can see it running by typing in the local host url, and can see it using wcftestclient.

I'm trying to use wsimport to generate code to access the service with the command:

```
wsimport http://..local host address.../DQServices.AddService.svc?wsdl -s c:\
```

and it shows -

```
parsing WSDL...

generating code...

compiling code...
```

but nothing returns or is written to c:\, is there a standard error associated with this or a way to get a more precise error output to see what's missing?

Comment: Perhaps the WSDL is blank? What do you get in the WSDL when you put that URL in the browser? Can you call this web service (or one of it's operations more accurately) from soapUI?

Answer (score 0):

I have once had a problem with writing directly to drive path such as `c:`. Could you please try to write to some other directory, perhaps choosing one that you are sure you have write access to will be a good idea.